# Core Data Transformable to UIImage using sqllite3

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data

I am working again on an old app that uses Core Data and my intention, for different reasons, is to migrate to Codable.

So far, I have got the .sqlite from the app application folder and exported it into my computer so I can see the structure. The table this question refers is that one.

[image]

To extract the content I am using a Helper class that reads the .sqlite file from the app application folder. So far I have managed to extract all the the information but when I try to get the UIImage from 'ZPICTURE' which is a transformable value UIImage stored as NSData I get a nil exception but the data is not nil.

I attache part of the function that handles all the .sqlite data extraction.

```
func startConvertion(){

    var albumArray:[AlbumC] = [AlbumC]()

    var db: OpaquePointer?
    //Open DB
    if sqlite3_open(dbFileURL.path, &db) == SQLITE_OK {

        print("\(logClassName) DB Openned successfuly")

        //Get Albums
        var albumQueryPointer:OpaquePointer?
        let albumQueryString = "SELECT * FROM ZALBUM"
        if sqlite3_prepare(db, albumQueryString, -1, &albumQueryPointer, nil) == SQLITE_OK{

            while(sqlite3_step(albumQueryPointer) == SQLITE_ROW){

                let pkAlbum = sqlite3_column_int(albumQueryPointer, 0)
                let albumName = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(albumQueryPointer, 4))
                let albumArtist = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(albumQueryPointer, 3))

                print("\(logClassName) Getting Album for \(pkAlbum) - \(albumArtist) - \(albumName)")
                let album = AlbumC(title: albumName, albumArtist: albumArtist)

                //Get Image Blob of data
                if let dataBlob = sqlite3_column_blob(albumQueryPointer, 5){
                    let dataBlobLength = sqlite3_column_bytes(albumQueryPointer, 5)

                    let blobNSData = NSData(bytes: dataBlob, length: Int(dataBlobLength))
                    //CRASH
                    let testImage = UIImage(data: blobNSData as Data)!

                    //album.artworkData = NSData(bytes: dataBlob, length: Int(dataBlobLength)) as Data
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you accessing the SQLite file directly?  Why not use the CoreData API to get the data?

Comment: because, if it is possible, I am thinking to remove all the Core Data legacy for the next release and that helper, "silently", will copy the existing content stored in the .sqllite file into the new model managed with the codable protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, what I was trying to achieve had sense. The old project was using CoreData and, among others, the table 'Album' used the NSManagedObject class 'Album'. So if, as requested, I needed to change the old model to implement the Codable protocol, the class 'Album' couldn't be used.

To be able to use a class with the old class name i had to remove all the CoreData dependencies and copy the content which was stored in the sql file to the new Codable class.

There are different ways to get the data from an sql file. I could have chosen 'SQL.swift' but, instead, I used 'sqlite3'.

So, the way to get a UIImage using sqlite3 from an sql file that contains a CoreData database and the value has been stored in a Transformable attribute type  is the following:

```
... FROM Question

    //Get Image Blob of data
    if let dataBlob = sqlite3_column_blob(albumQueryPointer, 5){

        let dataBlobLength = Int(sqlite3_column_bytes(albumQueryPointer, 5))
        if let aImage:UIImage = UIImage(data:NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with:Data(bytes:dataBlob, count:dataBlobLength)) as! Data){

            album.artwork = aImage

        }

    } 

...FROM Question
```

NSKeyedUnarchiver is the one that handles the UIImage from the blob data.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense, use CoreData to get this data out.

If you remove the class name from the CoreData entities then you can remove your managed object subclasses. You can still access the objects as raw NSManagedObjects.

Comment: So, If remove the CoreData the old .sql File gets deleted?

Comment: No it will still be there until you run code to clean up and delete it - after you have migrated across